# Base table or view not found laravel pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Posts table looks like.

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->string('image')->default('default.png');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->boolean('is_approved')->default(false);
        $table->boolean('status')->default(false);
        $table->integer('view_count')->default(0);
        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**User table.**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('role_id')->default(2);
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('image')->default('default.png');
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->text('about')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

When run php artisan:migrate got the error.

I can't find it.

There is my post_users table.

```
 Schema::table('post_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->foreign('post_id')
            ->references('id')->on('posts')
            ->onDelete('cascade')->unsigned()->index();
    });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lkj2X.png)

Comment: $table->increments('id'); add this code in post_users tables

Comment: add this, still same error

Comment: show me migration file location

Comment: database->migrations

Answer (score 2):

In `PostUsers` Model define table name

```
class PostUsers extends Model {
    public $table = "post_users";
```

**Update:**

Shouldn't

```
Schema::table('post_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->foreign('post_id')
        ->references('id')->on('posts')
        ->onDelete('cascade')->unsigned()->index();
});
```

be

```
Schema::create('post_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->foreign('post_id')
        ->references('id')->on('posts')
        ->onDelete('cascade')->unsigned()->index();
});
```

If you're going to create a new table you must use `Schema::create`

Comment: its not a model. i want to create a pivot table of post and user